# Is it possible to make memory card loads faster with ePSXe?

Tags: emulation, epsxe

I've googled around for this but couldn't find a result.  **Besides using the quick-save/load feature of ePSXe, is there a way to make the memory card become "detected" quicker for certain games?**

I'm playing FF7 again, and I like to use the save points as kind of a peace-of-mind backup.  When I go to save though, the memory card takes like 5 seconds to become "detected".  Is there a way to speed this up, ignoring the quick-save answer?

**Update:**

If it helps, I'm currently using Pete's OpenGL2 Driver 2.9 for my Video plugin.  Here are the settings:

[image]

**Update 2:**

OK, so I messed around with the FPS limits as per Xkeeper's method, and successfully toggled the frame limiter between all 3 states.  The only noticeable difference that happened is that in the FL2 state, the FPS stuck right at 59.8, while the others just hovered around 60.  Is there a way to change the 59.8?  I've tried changing all combinations of the radio buttons regarding the framerate in the settings image above, with no success.  The `[...]` button simply leads to button mappings.  I guess this question could be interpreted to the following now:  **Does anyone know how to fast forward with ePSXe, or forcibly set the FPS?**

An alternative option I've found is to try to switch to PSX Emulator, which has a fast forward button on the spacebar, but I'd rather not do that.

Comment: Is this an issue with the emulator? I assume an ideal emulator will behave as close as possible to the original hardware. Is this emulator behaving like the Playstation would behave playing the actual game? Is it a bug in the emulator implementation of the memory card emulation?

Comment: I guess that's what I'm asking.  It seems to take the same amount of time the playstation would.

Comment: Does the emulator have speed-up function? If it does, maybe you can assign function into a key on keyboard and make it into a habit of holding it every time you save. If the emulator is behaving like a real PSX, speeding it up might cause it to load the memory card faster

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on what graphics plugin you're using, you might be able to disable the framerate limit (which will speed up the game, normally). It varies based on plugin and version, but some hotkeys to try are F4 (toggles limit in ePSXe >= 1.7.0), 9 (unknown versions), and the later F-keys (F9 to F12), which adjust the frameskipping/limiting settings.

Check your video plugin's options screen to see what options it gives you.

Comment: I'll try this tonight when I get home.

Comment: There's also a "FPS limit" box in the config you potsed that you can try disabling (perhaps also check the `Show FPS display on startup` box and look at the [`...`] button next to it).

Comment: I've gotten this to toggle, but for some reason it sticks at 59.8 FPS.  Can you check my updated post and see if I'm missing something?

Comment: Make sure VSync is off. Check your video card setting too and make sure that it's not forcing VSync on for all applications.

Comment: My graphics card driver was limiting the framerate.  Thanks! This is perfect - I can now fast forward my ePSXe games!

Comment: Glad to hear it worked!

Comment: Note that the sound plugin could also lock you to 60 FPS. Set "P.E. Op. S. Sound Audio Driver 1.10" to Mode "2: Async simple (quality, fast-forward)", or use the "External SPU Plugin".

Answer (score 3):

An ideal emulator acts as close as possible to the original hardware when playing the game, so the issue you're describing, where memory cards take a lot of time to read, is probably an issue with the Playstation software or the game themselves. Aside from reverse engineering either of those, which I believe is beyond the scope of most people, there isn't anything you can do to alter the behiviour you're describing.

However, the fact that you're *emulating* the hardware, rather using the actual hardware, allows for some sort of workaround. I would check if your emulator or any other emulator allows for speeding up the emulation. This way you can force the emulator process to run faster momentarily, specifically when laoding the memory cards, to allow the process to finish quicker.

Another alternative, for Final Fantasy VII, at least, is to play the PC version. It doesn't allow for save states but is rather fast saving games.

Comment: FF7 PC has a whole host of *other* problems, though, so it's probably not a viable solution.

Comment: @Xkeeper Aside from compatibilty problems with new Windows versions, what other problems does the PC version have?

Comment: I played through FF7 my first time on PC, and I remember it having a lot more problems than how I'm playing it with ePSXe right now. Either way, I'm about halfway through and I don't think there's a way to transfer save states...

Comment: As for speeding up the game, I found this: http://www.fantasyanime.com/emuhelp/emuhelp_epsxe.htm#fastforward  I'll try it when I get home.